# What sort of connection is this cable?

Tags: cable

[image]

What cable is this. I do not recognize it.

Comment: They are quite common in external 2.5"  and SSD USB3.x drives

Answer (score 10):

This is a USB3 Micro-B cable. It may not be super common, but it isn't bizarre either. It's entirely standard.

Comment: I think it may also be relevant and important to note that the device which uses this USB interface is also backwards-compatible with a normal USB 2.0 Micro-B cable. It won't get USB 3 speeds, but it is (should be?) backwards-compatible.

Comment: I disagree. This is a bizarre workaround cable used as a stop-gap before USB C was adopted.